# Show Div once a user has entered text into text area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying to show my div id 'content2' only once a user has typed at least 4 characters into a text area?

I am trying to use the code below but its not working, please can someone show me where i am going wrong, thanks.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="field_post" name="vat" onfocus="document.getElementById('field_vat').style.background='#ffffff';" onkeyup="showDiv()" onchange="showDiv()"/>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
$("#field_post").on('keydown', function(event) {
    var currentString = $("#field_post").val()
    $("content2").html(currentString.length);
    if (currentString.length <= 500 )  {  /*or whatever your number is*/
      display:block;
    } else {
       display:none;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: People seem to be missing that you also want the length of the input string in the div as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("content2").innerHTML=document.getElementById("field_post").value.length;
 if (document.getElementById("field_post").value.length >=4 )  {  /*or whatever your number is*/
      document.getElementById("content2").style.display="block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("content2").style.display="none";
    }
```

Comment: this is not working for me, do i need to add something to my text area input html code to tell it where to point to the javascript?

Comment: You could add this inside `<script>` tags just before the `</body>` tag on the page. @user3584968

Comment: i've done that and it doesnt work, its still showing the div even if the text area is empty

Comment: Does not provide the correct answer / implementation. See my comment on the OP post.

Comment: @Metalstorm Did you mean this? (Edited)

Comment: @nicael That's right, at least now it matches the question (still hate the pure js) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `input` event that everyone seems to forget about. It fires when tae character is entered into an `input` instead of on any `keydown`.

```
$('#field_post').on('input', function () {
  var characterCount = this.value.length;
  $('#content2').text(characterCount).toggle(characterCount > 3);
});
```

Here is a small demo: http://jsbin.com/qoziwoha/2/edit

Comment: They want to put the length in the div as well.

Comment: Would be inclined to do `>=` as per my solution, so if they have a constant (could be dynamic as well I guess) they don't have to do `characterCount > SOME_CONSTANT - 1`

Comment: I like to leave a little for OP to think up on their own.

Comment: Always better to help as much as possible and give a bit of advice, the OP might not thing about things like this. (+ magic numbers are dirty)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in pure JS:

```
var field   = document.getElementById("field_post"),
    content = document.getElementById("content2");

field.onkeydown = function(){
  var len = this.value.length;
  content.innerHTML = len;

  if (len <= 4){
    content.style.display = "none";
  }else{
    content.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

Comment: If they already have access to jQuery ($?) why would you do this in pure js?

Comment: It's always better to use pure JS where possible. Plus, this really isn't a hard problem and using jQuery is kind of overkill on it. @Metalstorm

Comment: It's not always better using pure js over jQuery. The whole point in jQuery is so that its a common code path, tested, well documented and normally much shorter. Yes you do get a bit of overhead, but in an example like this it is inconceivable. JQuery is already included in their source, might as well use it.

Comment: I guess, but I (possibly wrongly) assumed that they were using jQuery to try and figure out this one issue and therefore pure js would have been better if it's used for just this. @Metalstorm

Comment: I would go as far as saying then they should be using some form of selector library instead of doing it in pure js ;) There are plenty of lightweight libraries out that that implement this functionality without the bloat and other features of jQuery.

Comment: Not sure it was worth a downvote though... And I'm not saying that they HAVE to use pure JS at all! I just thought it was a better method than including the whole of jQuery where it would include loads of irrelevant code, when it could be solved in a few lines of pure JS. It's perhaps not the best method but I still think it's better than a jQuery answer. @Metalstorm (Let me just say that this is down to opinion and in no way a 'fact' that my answer is better than an jQuery answer given!)

Comment: Like I said, they have already included jQuery syntax so they have access to it in their source. So it sound to take it for granted that it can be used, and rightly so. Unless this is literally the only thing they are using jQuery for then they should be using something much more lightweight, but still a selector library (like I said).

Comment: Which is an opinion @Metalstorm

Comment: @BeatAlex It's the opinion of the majority.

Comment: I don't understand why it's better to include a selector library (no matter how lightweight) for 10 lines of code. @Metalstorm

Comment: Because more than likely they will be doing other stuff else where, I would be surprised if this is the only js in the entire app that touches the DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood there sorry (probably on my part of doing a poor job of describing). I meant in this particular answer, I don't think it's worth noting that they should be using a selector library. If OP had stated that this was a portion of code within thousands of other lines of code, then yes, i'd include a note with a suggestion. But since this snippet of code is pretty simple, it seems unlikely OP would have a lot of code (a nasty speculation to make, but a truthful one). @Metalstorm

Answer (score 0):

Ok, regarding the problems:

#### First Problem

```
$("content2").html(currentString.length);
```

The css selector is looking for an element named `content2` whereas you would *probably* like to select a div with the **id** of content2, so for that to happen, you should write `$('#content2')`. If you wanted to select a div with the **class** `content2`, you would write `$('.content2')`.

#### Second problem

```
if (currentString.length <= 500 )  {  /*or whatever your number is*/
  display:block;
} else {
   display:none;
}
```

In the above snippet, you're typing in `display: block;`. Now that's not proper javascript code. You may be confused by the object syntax like `{ display: 'block' }` but in your code above, you don't have the wrapping curly braces `{}` to create an object. (The curly brackets that are present represent the `if () { } else { }` block.

The real problem, however, is that you're trying to add a css style on to the `#content2` element. In which case, the jQuery syntax is:

```
$('#content2').css('display', 'block');
```

The logic seems to be correct. Hope this helps.

Comment: Being picky, use `$('#content2').show()` More to the point, and less code ;)

Comment: Agreed, but I'm trying to keep it close to the original source. The main point of the post (and is the answer to the actual question) is *can someone show me where i am going wrong* with the following code.

Comment: What is? answering the question? If you're talking about using `show()`, let it go man :) Its not a big deal either way.

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#field_post").on('keydown', function(event)
{
    var len = $(this).val().length;
    if(len >= 4)
    {
        $('#content2').text(len).show();    
    }
}
```

This will show the div once, if the input length goes below 4 characters it will not be hidden again (as per your question). To acheive this instead change to:

```
$('#content2').text(len).toggle(!!len);
```